# pick a delimited value from array column in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a column in Hive whose Data type is array. Sample element  in the array column as below.

```
["US:DE:%:DT:AMER:USA:CA:Hermitage:12:Wilmington:11:M:NC:Coffee:"]
```

Each element in the array column is delimited by ':' , how can I pick 5th element which is 'AMER' based on data in hive. 
I tried `Split` function but it gave

> 'ClassCastException' error.

Comment: add sampel query here

Comment: select split(bg_group,":")[1] as col1 from sql_data

Answer (score 0):

Below Code worked

```
select  split(bg_group , ':')[4] from 
(
select 
explode( bg_group ) as bg_group from sql_data
) x
```